# Order of routeChangeStart event and rendering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-routing

I have a run function for a module and inside it there is a `$routeChangeStart` event binding. I would like to know time of the first routeChangeStart event triggered. I am expecting that it should be called immediately after first request but before any page render but it is not as I expected. It seems that the event is called after page started to be rendered.

```
  module.run(function ($location, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
         //do something with next.xxx
      });
   })
```

What is the expected behaviour? Or this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The event is fired before the page starts rendering, but that doesn't mean you'll catch it before the rendering begins. The event gets fired, then the next thing in the call stack is when Angular begins the page rendering (fetching the template, waiting for the route resolve property, etc) and you catch the event after that. From the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route)...

> Broadcasted before a route change. At this point the route services
>   starts resolving all of the dependencies needed for the route change
>   to occur. Typically this involves fetching the view template as well
>   as any dependencies defined in resolve route property. Once all of the
>   dependencies are resolved $routeChangeSuccess is fired.

If you need to do something like conditionally preventing the change, try using the [$locationChangeStart](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location) event instead. For example...

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
    if (someCondition) {
       event.preventDefault(); // prevent the change
    }
});
```

This will be run before Angular starts loading the new page.